# Powershell - Measure size of .tmp files (The property 'Length' cannot be found)

Tags: powershell, temporary-files, sccm, microsoft-bits

I am trying to measure the recursive size of a ccmcache directory that is currently being downloaded with BITS.

I am using the following Powershell script to measure the recursive size of the directory.

```
(Get-ChildItem $downloadPath -recurse | Measure-Object -property Length -sum).Sum
```

This script works for "normal" directories and files, but it fails with the following error if the directory only contains `.tmp` files.

```
Measure-Object : The property "Length" cannot be found in the input for any objects.
At line:1 char:27
+ (Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

How can I measure the recursive size of a directory that only contains `.tmp` files created by the BITS downloader.

Comment: How about just `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`? Did it output any file at all?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The problem was that the files were hidden and needed to be displayed with the `Get-ChildITem -Recurse -Hidden` switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that BITS `.tmp` files are hidden and `Get-ChildItem` only lists visible files by default.

To measure the size of the whole directory, including hidden files, the `-Hidden` switch must be passed.

```
(Get-ChildItem $downloadPath -Recurse -Hidden | Measure-Object -property Length -sum).Sum
```

But this would only count hidden files, excluding all visible files. So in order to count all files, the results of the hidden sum and visible sum must be added:

```
[long](Get-ChildItem $downloadPath -Recurse -Hidden | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum + [long](Get-ChildItem $downloadPath -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum
```

If no hidden files or visible files exist an error will occur. Because of that the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` switch is included.